# Help Identifying this Plant

Tags: nightshade, identification

I have a plant which I've been told is a Deadly Nightshade - but the more I look into it, the more skeptical I am - for a start the berries are in large clusters, and it looks to me like a tree rather then a bush ( This relates to question [this link](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/24870/getting-rid-of-deadly-nightshade)    where I ask how to get rid of it !).  I'd really appreciate help identifying this plant.

I speculate that it must be some kind of nightshade based on the flowers and leaves.

I live in North Auckland, New Zealand, equivalent to US Hardiness zone 9.  I suspect that the plant is not more then 2 years old.

[image: Plant Image]
[image: Closeup of Leaves]
[image: Closeup of Flowers]
[image: Closeup of Berries]

The berries are about the size of cherries.

I have a couple of these on my property - about 20 meters apart, but they do not appear to be "taking over".

Comment: That's no nightshade I know of.

Comment: @GardenerJ  good question though

Comment: @kevinsky Oh definitely, plenty of description, nice pictures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like [Woolly Nightshade](http://www.weedbusters.org.nz/weed-information/solanum-mauritianum/59/) *Solanum mauritianum*:
[image: Flowers]
[image: Seeds]

Invasive in NZ, gets up to 10 meters tall.
Comes from South America. Once established in a new area, it's spread by birds.
In Africa, they call it [bugweed](http://keys.lucidcentral.org/keys/v3/eafrinet/weeds/key/weeds/Media/Html/Solanum_mauritianum_%28Bugweed%29.htm).

The [berries are toxic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solanum_mauritianum) to humans, containing [solasodine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solasodine), a chemical relative of the potato skin toxin, [solanine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solanine).